# I want to add onclick on textfield of material ui so that if i click anywhere it will open date selector

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i should be able to click anywhere in date field and add date but i dont how to do

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
                <TextField
                  placeholder={"Start Date"}
                  variant="outlined"
                  margin="normal"
                  type="date"
                  name="startDate"
                  value={cohortInput?.startDate}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
</FormControl>
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you are not able to use DatePicker?  https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/